# look in xml element and return next column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, xmlhttprequest

the xDocument response returns:

```
<Result>
  <Value>FAIL</Value>
  <Message>Error in Cloud/Upload - No Client Account exists</Message>
</Result>
```

in my below code if .Equals(Fail) I wat to throw an error containing the 
 XDocument response = XDocument.Parse(infoAsString);

```
        if (response.Root.Name.LocalName.Equals("Result"))
        {
            try
            {
                if (response.Root.Elements.Equals("FAIL"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error:" + //Message from xml);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, if your response is [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
response.SelectSingleNode("//Message").InnerText
```

If not would be a lot easier to use `XmlDocument` see below:

```
   XmlDocument respDoc = new XmlDocument();
   respDoc.LoadXml(xml_string);
   if(respDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Value").InnerText.Trim() == "FAIL")
    {
       throw new Exception("Error:" + response.SelectSingleNode("//Message").InnerText);
    }
```

Ofcouse if you want it with XDocument then use :

```
response.Root.Element("Message").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using your existing `XDocument` (notice my comment about your check for "FAIL"):

```
if (response.Root.Name.LocalName.Equals("Result"))
{
    try
    {
        //response.Root.Elements.Equals("FAIL") won't do what you want, try this:
        var val = response.Root.Element("Value").Value;

        if (val == "FAIL")
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: " + response.Root.Element("Message").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats great thanks for the reply, do I need to also check if the xelement is != null?

Comment: If you have reason to believe that it could be null, then yes. If it is a truly exceptional condition, then perhaps not and let your exception-handling deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `try / catch` if the response (once determined to be a `<Result>`) is guaranteed to have the XML structure you provided.

```
if (response.Root.Name.LocalName == "Result")
{
    if (response.Root.Element("Value").Value == "FAIL")
    {
        throw new Exception("Error: " + response.Root.Element("Message").Value);
    }
}
```